# Connection error with QGIS 3.0 Metasearch plugin

Tags: qgis, metadata

I've added "Data.gov" as a service in the Metasearch plugin (QGIS 3.0 32-bit). The associated URL is https://catalog.data.gov/csw-all.  When I click "Service info" I receive a response describing the service.  However, when I attempt conduct a search (e.g., "roads") using this service I receive the following error:

```
             Connection error: mismatched tag: line 4, column 2
```

Any thoughts on what the problem may be?

Comment: I get the same error when searching that on a 64bit Linux QGIS 3 for that data.gov service even with no search value, but I don't on another CSW service `http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/csw?`  so it might be an error in the CSW response (or the response is different to to that which the metaseach plugin is expecting)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

It looks very much like there is an issue with the CSW response from the data.gov service (wondering whether this is related to it being provided through Amazon CloudFront, or it using HTTPS).

---

Looking at other CSW services.

`http://onegeology-geonetwork.brgm.fr/geonetwork3/srv/eng/csw?`

If I search with no parameters then metasearch sends an HTTP POST request like:

```
<csw:GetRecords xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" maxRecords="10" outputFormat="application/xml" outputSchema="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" resultType="results" service="CSW" version="2.0.2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
  <csw:Query typeNames="csw:Record">
    <csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>
  </csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
```

and I get a response like below which populates the list of services/data to be added to QGIS...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<csw:GetRecordsResponse xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
  <csw:SearchStatus timestamp="2018-03-17T12:34:42" />
  <csw:SearchResults numberOfRecordsMatched="490" numberOfRecordsReturned="10" elementSet="full" nextRecord="11">
    <csw:Record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:geonet="http://www.fao.org/geonetwork" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
      <dc:identifier>1c25e8926d8f77f28ef68accefc59f14bb240285</dc:identifier>
      <dc:date>2017-05-30T09:42:18</dc:date>
      <dc:title>Web Map Service CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY</dc:title>
      <dc:type>service</dc:type>
      <dc:subject>ArcIMS</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>OneGeology</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>geology</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>Canada</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>continent@Northern America</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>geographicarea@Canada</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>subarea@Ontario</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>serviceprovider@Ontario Geological Survey</dc:subject>
      <dc:subject>dataprovider@Ontario Geological Survey</dc:subject>
      <dc:format />
      <dct:abstract>ArcIMS 9.1.0CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY Web Map Service</dct:abstract>
      <dc:description>ArcIMS 9.1.0CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY Web Map Service</dc:description>
      <dc:source />
      <dc:format />
      <dc:URI protocol="OGC:WMS-1.1.1-http-get-capabilities">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
      <dc:URI protocol="OGC:WMS" name="faultsat250k">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
      <dc:URI protocol="OGC:WMS" name="dikesat250k">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
      <dc:URI protocol="OGC:WMS" name="ironformationsat250k">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
      <dc:URI protocol="OGC:WMS" name="bedrockat250k">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
      <dc:URI protocol="application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml" description="http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?">http://www.geologyontario.mndm.gov.on.ca:80/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/CAN_ON_OGS_250K_BEDROCK_AND_STRUCTURAL_GEOLOGY?</dc:URI>
    </csw:Record>
    ...
```

I tried on another service the HTTP POST request is the same, but I get an error reported in QGIS, which the popup tells me is:

```
Raised exception while getting metadata :org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

As this service is using HTTP it's easy for me to sniff the response and I can see it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>Raised exception while getting metadata :org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

So the service is not working as expected and I get the reported error relayed to me through the QGIS popup.

So now we have `Connection error: mismatched tag: line 4, column 2`
 as the popup message, most likely this is a message reported by the CSW, but it it could be that the response is some default message of owslib (which metasearch is using), when the actual response can't be parsed.